# How to alter the position of block in sidebar

Tags: product, layout, product-page, sidebar

I want to change the position of block in my category pages. I tried in some xml file but couldn't get success.

Any idea would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: @Erfan : I tried in catalog.xml to alter the block reference and it doesn't work. something i expect to change is before and after attribute to be placed in block reference but where and what i am not able to figure out if i am correct.

Comment: are you want to remove  only price block? or all filter and  put the newsletter on this section

Comment: None of the block i want to remove i just want to alter the positon of block... like first block compare products , second block newsletter block then shop by block....@AmitBera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess thats the correct answer for Kishor

```
<block type="cms/block" name="BLOCK_1" before="-"> 
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>BLOCK_1</block_id></action> 
</block> 
<block type="cms/block" name="BLOCK_2" after="BLOCK_1"> 
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>BLOCK_1</block_id></action> 
</block> 
<block type="cms/block" name="BLOCK_3" after="BLOCK_2">
     <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>customer-rev</block_id></action> 
</block>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had done like this and it is working fine as i wanted.